# Get remote host status information and details using PHP

Tags: php, status

I'm looking to get server details from a remote server using PHP.  I know I can get some details by just grabbing the headers, but I also want to get the server up time, bandwidth usage, etc.  If you could tell me how to do this or point me in the right direction, I would be appreciative.

Comment: What OS is the system running?  SNMP would be a good starting point though.

Comment: Do you control this remote server? You can't just ask a random server these things...

Comment: @ceejayoz I do not control the remote servers.  I know it would be a hit and miss in most cases, but I WOULD be in contact with the people who do control the other servers, though.

Comment: Well info like bandwidth and uptime will not be accessible externally any way unless you make it available.  For linux systems running an SNMP daemon would be the way to go.  Windows, I guess you'd have to query WMI or something like that.

Comment: The people running the remote servers would need to set something up for you to get this data, then.

Comment: @ceejayoz I do believe you are right.  I was hoping there was some sort of server detail information "whatever" accessible by any script that would give some basic server stats, but it doesn't seem that way.

Comment: Would you want competitors knowing your bandwidth usage? It could be valuable info.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this?

http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/
or 
http://www.zabbix.com/

Zabbix is professional yet opensource network monitoring system and works excellent and could provide you all info you're looking for. It's frontend is written completely in PHP so you can hack into it the way you want.

**EDIT:**

Basically you can't get all the information that you're looking for without installing some program or tools on server which can monitor these parameters for you and return you back.
May be you can get "`uptime`" by executing command using exe(`uptime`) or something similar but for bandwidth usage I think it would be difficult to get unless you get it by firing some commands in background in your php script.
Some of the utilities which might help you do that would be `ifstat` or `iftop` but they are not installed by default on ubuntu/debian based systems so if you want to use them you need to install them so not possible w/o access to machine.

Comment: If you're using Apache you could use either webalizer or awstats programs. Which could give you quite detailed stats for data transfer, requests and much more...

For uptime you could always use free 3rd party monitoring services like pingdom or uptimerobot.

http://blogs.digitss.com/reviews/best-free-website-uptime-monitor/

Comment: No, not yet.  I don't have access to the servers I need to get the info on.  The user would have to voluntarily install something.  Right now, I'm just looking to see what is open to the public without anyone having to install anything.

Comment: Can you add to this answer to say that there is really no way to get all the information I want without installing a program on the server directly?  This way I can mark this as the answer as well.